# Rails 3 console and db:console are different

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite, activerecord

I have a rails app and when I have both the console and db:console open, they have different values for what is supposed to be the same field.  I am using the send function to change the value.  Here is the method in the model:

```
  def toggle_approve(field)
    self.send(field)
    if(self.send(field).blank?)
        self.send(field + '=', "new_value")
        puts self.send(field)
    else
        self.send(req + '=', "")
    end
    rank.save
  end
```

In my db:console (sqllite) everything is always correct, but in my regular erb console it is wrong.  My view will then show what is in the erb console and not the sqllite.  I dont understand what is going on in the background that would causing this issue.  Any help would be great.

Comment: Could not understand clearly. But, Try to delete your data's in your table that existing and try again. Sometimes, it will give different values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to be sure from the details you provided, but I think it is the case that your view uses an obsolete version of the data. Try calling `.reload` on the updated record, just at the point after the update and before presentation. See if that fixes your problem.

Comment: You are correct, but how can the view be based against a moving target like that?  How do we debug against it?  Is there a way to make the view based against the backing db and not what is in the console, or is there a way to reload the data after every call?

Comment: This is the difference between MVC and binding patterns. Data is retrieved by the controller, and it's the one that needs to update the view. Your best choice would probably be to redesign it so you get the same functionality, but don't need the reloading. If you can't help it, then determine the cases where you have to reload, and automate the behavior, either in helpers, or in the model itself.

Comment: Is there a documentation that would show when the data is updated and how?  I will refactor it, but I would like some direction in the best way to do this?  In a prod app, does it work the same as in dev?  Or would the functionality I have here work in prod the same?

Comment: The data is never updated automatically. However, you can create a static method to register an instance in the class, and then another one to reload all registered instances. You can then register the problematic instances, and call your own implemented `reload_instances` static method in the console, or wherever you wish.

Comment: Also I was thinking that I could just update the UI, let the Ajax request fly, and not worry about it.  The backend is working, but the UI is caching or something.  Or could I use `uncached do ... end` and that also might work.  What do you think?

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't very good for iterative discussion, so you could submit a new question that demonstrates what you want to do and supply all the pertinent code since the question has changed (this question asked the "why" and now you'd like some advice on the "how").